# Display(Enable) ActionBar when dialog is shown

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

How to Display ActionBar when Dialog is shown in Android? My ActionBar should be enabled even when dialog is appeared.
In my app it is becoming dim when dilog is appeared.

Comment: You should create popup rather than dialog, 
see following post of mine it may help you to create popup

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.*;

public class ShowPopUp extends Activity {

    PopupWindow popUp;
    LinearLayout layout;
    TextView tv;
    LayoutParams params;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    Button but;
    boolean click = true;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        tv = new TextView(this);
        but = new Button(this);
        but.setText("Click Me");
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (click) {
                    popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
                    popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
                    click = false;
                } else {
                    popUp.dismiss();
                    click = true;
                }
            }

        });
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
        layout.addView(tv, params);
        popUp.setContentView(layout);
        // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
        mainLayout.addView(but, params);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you